# Solving for $\theta$ in a nested sine function

Tags: trigonometry

I currently have the function:

\begin{equation}
\cos(1.3\pi\cos(\theta)) - \cos(1.3\pi) = 0
\end{equation}

but am unsure if it is possible to solve this analytically. I have looked over possible trig identities and have not found one that may be useful.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My textbook refers to both cosine and sine as sine functions, so I assumed that this terminology was correct

Comment: Use trigonometric equations. If $cos{x} = cos{y}$, then $x = 2n\pi \pm y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using whole numbers, you want to solve
$$\cos \left(\frac{13}{10} \pi  \cos (t)\right)=\cos \left(\frac{13\pi  }{10}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$ Taking the inverse
$$t=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{10 }{13 \pi }\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\right)$$ modulo ... something.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is as follows:

$$\cos{(1.3\pi\cos{\theta})} = \cos{1.3\pi}$$

Using the identity I gave above,

$$1.3\pi\cos{\theta} = 2n\pi\pm\ 1.3\pi.....n\in Z$$

Dividing both sides by $1.3\pi$, we get,

$$\cos{\theta} = \frac{20n}{13}\pm1$$

Solve for inequalities
$$-1<\frac{20n}{13}+1<1$$

and
$$-1<\frac{20n}{13}-1<1$$

since $\cos{\theta} \in [-1,1]$. Then take inverse cosine for the solutions you get.